# Why does Xamarin Absolute Layout stacking not respect Children order

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, absolutelayout

I am trying to achieve a layout where the content has an image on background (positioned in bottom left corner, expanding 100% vertically and 60% horizontally)

The whole content is wrapped in an AbsoluteLayout, the main content is then a child to this layout and consists of StackLayout (and some other content inside).

The previewer in Visual Studio (Visual Studio Community 2017) shows the layout correctly - the image is below the content, the content is placed on middle as intended. However, both VS Emulator and Genymotion show the image above the content.

I trimmed the code to be as readable as possible (stripping it of styling)

...

```
        <Frame VerticalOptions="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Margin="0" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,0.6,1">
            <Image Source="Graphic_Anna.png" />
        </Frame>

        <!-- Start: Actual Page Content -->
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="ApplicationLayoutContentLevel">

            <Label Text="This is some text in main content" />

        </StackLayout>
        <!-- End: Actual Page Content -->

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

...

The expected result is shown on this screenshot (from Previewer): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ViL6.png

However, the result in both emulator seems to do this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNheE.png

**Unfortunately, I don't have the option to test the app on an actual Android phone at this moment**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieved like the following screenshot?
I do not know which size that you used, so I cutout the picture from your screenshot.

[image]

If so, there is my code.If you want to achieve coveraged effect, I used two `stacklayout`, the first layout will be covered by the second layout.Notice:If you set the `VerticalOptions` will affect the `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds`

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>


        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Margin="0" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,0.6,1">

            <Image Source="Graphic_Anna.png" />

        </StackLayout>
        <!-- Start: Actual Page Content -->
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8,0.7,0.5,0.5"  x:Name="ApplicationLayoutContentLevel">
            <Image Source="start.png"  Scale="0.7"/>
            <Label Text="10/10" TextColor="Black" FontSize="50" Margin="20,10,0,0"/>
            <Label Text="Great job! you got everything" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
            <Label Text="Back to games" TextColor="red"  Margin="25,20,0,0"  />
        </StackLayout>
    <!-- End: Actual Page Content -->

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. In the end I created fullsize <StackLayout> with nested <AbsoluteLayout> containing all graphics in the background and it works really nicely.

Comment: Ok, happy coding.